# How to use multiple data sources in micronaut

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I have two schemas for my application. One for regular customer data and another for analytics purpose.

I want to use one data source for customer data related domain objects & other data source for analytics related domain objects.

I am new to micronaut. I see micronaut `application.yml` file supports multiple data sources to configure. Micronuat uses default data source by default.

Is there a way to configure datasource at a domain level like grails entity.

I'm using frontier schema for Person domain.

```
class Person {
    String guid
    String name

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'frontier'
        table 'person'
    }
}
```

Using analytics schema for Event domain.

```
class Event {
    String guid
    String action

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'analytics'
        table 'person_event'
    }
}
```

In Grails, operations on each domain are happened based on the given datasource.

How to achieve the same functionality in micronaut using multiple data sources ?

Comment: If you want to go with "gorm" library entities instead of micronaut-data library, then you can find solution for this question in the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73662973/getting-no-session-found-for-current-thread-error-while-using-multiple-data-so

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to configure datasource at a domain level like grails
> entity.

There is a way to configure datasource at a domain level, but it isn't the way you would do it in Grails.  In Micronaut Data the datasource may be specified using `@Repository` or `@TransactionalAdvice`.

An example from [micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/3.7.3/guide/#dbcRepositories](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/3.7.3/guide/#dbcRepositories):

```
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.ORACLE, dataSource = "inventoryDataSource") 
@TransactionalAdvice("inventoryDataSource") 
public interface PhoneRepository extends CrudRepository<Phone, Integer> {
    Optional<Phone> findByAssetId(@NotNull Integer assetId);
}
```